# My CachedNetworkImage doesn't change when value changed

Tags: dart, flutter

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var switchButton = new Switch(
        value: detail,
        onChanged: (bool value){
          setState(() {
            detail = value;
          });
        },
    );
    var imagejadwal = new CachedNetworkImage(
      imageUrl: switchButton.value?"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1v-dA5bG7Fwk_hJvL2wu4Z9P10JdsaWIe":"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1qfdI_yM7rzdLMqRizlr76445qc0IQKhD",
      placeholder: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
      errorWidget: new Icon(Icons.error),
    );

    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
            child: switchButton,
          ),
          imagejadwal,
        ],
      )
    );
  }
```

> It's because the CachedNetworkImage or my code is wrong ? Can someone
>   help me ? I'm still new at flutter Thank you.

Lib: https://github.com/renefloor/flutter_cached_network_image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the code of aziza, but it also didn't work for me.

I changed a bit of code in the CachedNetworkImage and that seems to work, I changed the 'didUpdateWidget':

```
@override
void didUpdateWidget(CachedNetworkImage oldWidget) {
  super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  if (widget.imageUrl != oldWidget.imageUrl ||
    widget.placeholder != widget.placeholder){

  _imageProvider = new CachedNetworkImageProvider(widget.imageUrl,
      errorListener: _imageLoadingFailed);

  _resolveImage();
  }
}
```

It needs to change its ImageProvider. I made an [issue](https://github.com/renefloor/flutter_cached_network_image/issues/16) for that on github

You could also use a Stack. In that way you have more control over the animation from one image to the other. For example

```
            class _CachedImageExampleState extends State<CachedImageExample> {
              bool switchState = true;

              @override
              Widget build(BuildContext context) {
                var switchButton = new Switch(
                  value: switchState,
                  onChanged: (bool value) {
                    setState(() {
                      switchState = value;
                    });
                  },
                );
                var imagejadwal1 = new CachedNetworkImage(
                  imageUrl: "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1v-dA5bG7Fwk_hJvL2wu4Z9P10JdsaWIe",
                  placeholder: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  errorWidget: new Icon(Icons.error),
                );


                var imagejadwal2 = new CachedNetworkImage(
                  imageUrl: "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1qfdI_yM7rzdLMqRizlr76445qc0IQKhD",
                  placeholder: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  errorWidget: new Icon(Icons.error),
                );

                return new Scaffold(
                    appBar: new AppBar(
                      title: new Text("TestImage"),
                    ),
                    body: new Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                          child: switchButton,
                        ),
                        new Container (
                          //width: 500.0,
                          ///container to deal with the overflow, you may not want to use it with hardcoded
                          ///height because it will not allow the view to be responsive, but it is just to
                          ///make a point about dealing with the overflow
                            height: 400.0,
                            child: new Stack(children: <Widget>[
                              new Opacity(opacity: switchState ? 1.0 : 0.0, child: imagejadwal1),
                              new Opacity(opacity: switchState ? 0.0 : 1.0, child: imagejadwal2,)
                            ],)),
                      ],
                    )
                );
              }
            }
```

I noticed that the animation of the switch is not shown when the second image (the blue one) is being shown. It is a very large image (2550x3300), consider making that one smaller to improve the performance of the app.

Comment: Rene, do you know how to display the image fill all in background ?

Comment: Use fit: [BoxFit](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/BoxFit-class.html).cover in the CachedNetworkImage constructor.

Comment: Please mark this answer as correct when it is the thing you looked for.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine, however you have got two issue to deal with:

1. The images are overflowing and may be preventing the UI from updating.
2. The images are too big, and you need to wait a little bit for them to load.

I have modified a little bit of your code:

[image]

```
class _CachedImageExampleState extends State<CachedImageExample> {
  bool switchState = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var switchButton = new Switch(
      value: switchState,
      onChanged: (bool value) {
        setState(() {
          switchState = value;
        });
      },
    );
    var imagejadwal = new CachedNetworkImage(
      imageUrl: switchState
          ? "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1v-dA5bG7Fwk_hJvL2wu4Z9P10JdsaWIe"
          : "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1qfdI_yM7rzdLMqRizlr76445qc0IQKhD",
      placeholder: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
      errorWidget: new Icon(Icons.error),
    );
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("TestImage"),
        ),
        body: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topRight,
              child: switchButton,
            ),
            new Container (
              //width: 500.0,
              ///container to deal with the overflow, you may not want to use it with hardcoded
              ///height because it will not allow the view to be responsive, but it is just to
              ///make a point about dealing with the overflow
                height: 400.0,
                child: imagejadwal),
          ],
        )
    );
  }
}
```

I managed to fix your issue, there are two implementations for this plugin and the following one should fix it for you. I am not sure the reason behind state not updating (probably imageUrl can not be overriden)

Anyway, here is your fix:

```
class CachedImageExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CachedImageExampleState createState() => new _CachedImageExampleState();
}

class _CachedImageExampleState extends State<CachedImageExample> {
  bool toggle = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var switchButton = new Switch(
      value: toggle,
      onChanged: (bool value) {
        setState(() {
          toggle = value;
        });
      },
    );
    var img= new Image(image: new CachedNetworkImageProvider(
        toggle
            ? "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1v-dA5bG7Fwk_hJvL2wu4Z9P10JdsaWIe"
            : "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1qfdI_yM7rzdLMqRizlr76445qc0IQKhD"));


    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("TestImage"),
        ),
        body: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topRight,
              child: switchButton,
            ),
            new Container (
                width: 200.0,
                height: 200.0,
                child: img),
          ],
        )
    );
  }
}
```

**Update : Fit the image to the whole screen**

```
class CachedImageExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CachedImageExampleState createState() => new _CachedImageExampleState();
}

class _CachedImageExampleState extends State<CachedImageExample> {
  bool toggle = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var switchButton = new Switch(
      activeColor: Colors.amber,
      activeTrackColor: Colors.amberAccent,
      inactiveThumbColor: Colors.amber,
      value: toggle,
      onChanged: (bool value) {
        setState(() {
          toggle = value;
        });
      },
    );

    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          actions: <Widget>[
            switchButton
          ],
          title: new Text("TestImage"),
        ),
        body:
            new Container (
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                image: new DecorationImage(
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    image:
                new CachedNetworkImageProvider(
                    toggle
                        ? "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1v-dA5bG7Fwk_hJvL2wu4Z9P10JdsaWIe"
                        : "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1qfdI_yM7rzdLMqRizlr76445qc0IQKhD"
                )
                ),
              ),

),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It's still same ._. doesn't change

Comment: How can your's code work, i tested in my flutter it doesn't change

Comment: sir ? can you help me ?

Comment: I am having issues with my flutter right now, and I am confused why it does not work with you

Comment: thx man, can you tell me how to show the image fit all screen ?

Comment: What do you mean by the whole screen ? You have a switch button how can your image fit the whole screen ?

Comment: fit all below the switch button

Comment: It would make your life much easier if you can move the switch button up in the AppBar as long as you want the whole screen for the image, check the update to know what I mean.

Comment: Im very surprised, thanks man you really helped me. i'm beginner at flutter, thank you very much !